# display live image from an usb PC camera in windows application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webcam, windows-forms-designer

I want to display live image from the usb PC webcam using C# windows application in Visual Studio 2010. I have searched about that and find the link http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition but when i tried this code

```
           WIA.CommonDialog class1 = new WIA.CommonDialog();
            Device d = class1.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);
            if (d != null)
            {
                settings.DeviceID = d.DeviceID;
                settings.Save();
            }
```

I am getting the giving compilation error

```
error CS0103: The name 'settings' does not exist in the current context
```

And I am not able to find out the solution for this error.
Can anybody body please tell me what would be the solution for this error?
And Is there any other best method to display live images from usb webcam?

Any help would be appreciated....

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: This example doesn't show where "settings" is declared. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f(v=vs.80).aspx

If you could post some more code that would be great.

Comment: see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you haven't defined a settings object, however it doesn't seem to be in the  tutorial either. Personally though I would use AForge.NET library as this provides an extremely easy interface to webcams.

http://aforgenet.com/

Tutorial: http://vimeo.com/7526663

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AForge.NET is very powerful library. But for testing purporse or simple project you could use WIA. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/catch-a-snapshot-via-your-webcam-using-C-Sharp-part-vii/) - small example how to start